# using an output of a transaction in the same transaction

Tags: plutus, eutxo

is it possible to implement a plutus script that consumes two UTXO's where the output of one is used as an redeemer for the second?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I have it clear, but you can't use outputs of one transaction as inputs in the same transaction because every UTxO is unique and once used, you can't reuse it.

But you can use as many eUTxO's as you want in your transaction. It makes eUTxO model very powerful because you can involve many validator scripts and minting policies in same transaction.

Comment: What I would like to do is link contracts, I would guess that this is possible but I do see how the Plutus.tx functions need to be used to implement this. Say is have an script at address 1 that mints an NFT for 10 ada, also consider a script at address 2 which create an action. Then I would like to link these two scripts in one transaction.

Comment: Yes, you can do that in the same transaction.